# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec() throwing error when file path contains spaces

Tags: java, exception, process, runtime, exec

The Java code:

```java
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().ecex("C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Firefox.exe");
```

throws the exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start": CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
```

He can't handle the space at the folder name `Start Menu`, I think.

Is there an escape sequence to handle spaces?

I've no idea, what I can do?
I only try to use the German folder names, but it will be the same.

Comment: `new ProcessBuilder("C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Firefox.exe").inheritIO().start()` would be better.. `ProcessBuilder` is generally easier to use, but always pass arguments as an array or `List` (in this case implied). You need to double backslashes in Java strings to escape the backslash but better to use forward slashes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Runtime Exec With White Spaces On Path Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33077129/java-runtime-exec-with-white-spaces-on-path-name)

Comment: Incidentally, if your objective is to open a web browser, you might find methods in `java.awt.Desktop` easier and more robust

Comment: using `exec(String)`, the method with one String parameter, is known to separate the string using spaces as separator - actually its documentation states that it is deprecated and explicitly mention "*This method is error-prone and should not be used, the corresponding method exec(String[]) or ProcessBuilder should be used instead. The command string is broken into tokens using only whitespace characters. For an argument with an embedded space, such as a filename, this can cause problems as the token does not include the full filename.*"

Comment: I should have been less abstract in my comments about `java.awt.Desktop`. Prefer this as it will make your code less likely to fail and more portable (*if* your objective is to open a browser) as **a.** not everyone will have that browser, and/or **b.** not everyone's Firefox will be at that location and **c.** even on the box that you're running this, the location of the executable might change

Comment: I don't think that the command you're running is an actual command. The location indicates it's your system-wide start menu, so most likely the `Firefox.exe` is actually `Firefox.exe.lnk` - a shortcut.

Comment: @RobSpoor - yes. I thought there was something weird about it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
The "Start Menu" - folder is a virtual folder, only windows has access, so I searched for the "firefox.exe" in my folder system and found it, than I used this folder "C:/program (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe". My program (a sidebar) is running now. When I click on firefox, firefox will start.
Thanx for your help.

Comment: @Rob Spoor has already mentioned that. Also, it doesn't affect what I said about hard-coding browser access